# Ajax form validation json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I've got a problem with my ajax contactform validation. The error checking works a little bit. If i type in a wrong email-adres, it also validates the empty name field, i tried different things, but i think i'm missing a small part. If you answer my question, could you please explain the changes, i really want to learn!

This is my code (or see this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/IfUpuRa/1)):

Ajax Call

```
    $('form.ajax').on("keyup", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this   =   $(this);
                data    =   {};

            $this.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
                var $this   =   $(this),
                    name    =   $this.attr('name');
                    value   =   $this.val();

                data[name] = value;
            });


            $.ajax({
                url : "contact.php",
                type: "post",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",

                success: function(response){

                    error_check(response);
                }
            });


        });
```

Function i use to check my errors and add the error message

```
     function error_check(arr){

        $.each(arr, function(key, value){

            var el = $('li.' + key);

            if(value == true){

                if( el.hasClass('error') ){
                    $(el).removeClass('error')
                         .children('div.error').remove()
                         .addClass('validated')
                         .prepend('<div class="validated"></div>');
                }else{
                    $(el)
                        .addClass('validated')
                        .prepend('<div class="validated"></div>');
                }

            }else if(value == false){

                if( el.hasClass('validated') ){
                    $(el).removeClass('validated')
                         .children('div.validated').remove()
                         .addClass('error')
                         .prepend('<div class="error"></div>');
                }else{
                    $(el)
                        .addClass('error')
                        .prepend('<div class="error"></div>');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my php validation code:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$validated = array();

$name       =    $_POST['name'];
$company    =    $_POST['company'];
$email      =    $_POST['email'];
$phone      =    $_POST['phone'];
$date       =    $_POST['date'];


/*Ajax validation*/

if(!empty($name) && strlen($name) >= 2){
    $validated['name'] = true;
}else{
    $validated['name'] = false;
}


if( !empty($email) ){
    $validate_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);        

    if($validate_email){
        $validated['email'] = true;
    }else{
        $validated['email'] = false;
    }
}

echo json_encode($validated);
}else{
die();
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you validate after every keystroke instead of after form submission?

Comment: I have build a timeout function for that, so i think that is not a problem. But i decided to get rid of that function in this example.

Comment: Doing that on purpose doesn't make it better. Why are you trying to mimick (in a very bad way) a native solution? Use `submit()`. Could you please provide the relevant DOM in a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/) with your javascript (don't forget to mock the ajax call)?

Comment: I want to check the credentials during the contact-process, not after submitting the form. If there is another way to doing this, i would like to learn that way!

Here is my jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/IfUpuRa/1

Thank you for your comment

Comment: But what exactly do you gain by checking them while typing? Nothing. Because you `post` afterwards to the same page (where you run the same checks **again** - like x times before - after every keypress).

Comment: The fields are animated with css3, so all the error animations are playing on the keypress (animated creatures that build the error message etc.). It is not the ideal solution, but it is necessary for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post request doesn't contain a `date` property (at least in your jsBin example) and that triggers an error. It is generelly more advisable to check for the existence of parameters beforehand:

```
$name       =    (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
$company    =    (isset($_POST['company']) ? $_POST['company'] : null;
$email      =    (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$phone      =    (isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : null;
$date       =    (isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : null;

// check required parameters and exit if they're missing
if (is_null($name) || is_null($email)) {
    // some error handling here
} else {
    // and (almost) the rest of your existing script goes here
}

echo json_encode($validated);
```

[edit] And concerning your "validate-on-every-keypress" approach: a far better approach would be to leverage the html5 input types (e.g. `<input type="email"…>`) and do some simple validation on the client before submission (you don't do that much, so it should be pretty straight forward). You obviously still need to validate on the backend (but you just reduced the traffic to practically zero)!